Pass result of external to internal command
I'd like to pass the result of an external command to an internal command, and bind the result to a key. More concretely, I'd like to do something like the following in .tigrc:
bind main <Ctrl-r> :goto $(git merge-base %(commit) main)

The above isn't possible. Have I missed an alternative method?
